# Applying filter to Access Subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

Maybe this one is easy, because i was able to do it via a simple Macro before, but via VBA i just couldn't get it right.

I'm trying via VBA to filter a subform by trying to apply a DoCmd.Applyfilter command.

I have a data field called TxtToday which has Date() as a default value. I would like to apply on form load a filter which would filter the records on subform which have the same date as the TxtToday field.

As of now i have this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

DoCmd.ApplyFilter DATE_FOLLOWUP = TxtToday

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any code at all.

Use the *LinkMasterFields* and *LinkChildFields* of the subform control holding the subform. Set the master field to `TxtToday` and the child field to `DATE_FOLLOWUP`.

Comment: Thank you. Worked very well.